# TypeError: object () takes no parameters - python

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to write a program with class and object. Following is my code:

```
class Animal:
    __name = ""
    __height = 0
    __weight = 0
    __sound = 0

# define a constructor and pass arguments
def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
    self.__name = name
    self.__height = height
    self.__weight = weight
    self.__sound = sound


# set and get functions for name
def set_name(self, name):
    self.__name = name

def get_name(self):
    return self.__name


# set and get functions for height
def set_height(self, height):
    self.__height = height

def get_height(self):
    return str(self.__height)


# set and get functions for weight
def set_weight(self, weight):
    self.__weight = weight


def get_weight(self):
    return str(self.__weight)


# set and get functions for sound
def set_sound(self, sound):
    self.__sound = sound

def get_sound(self):
    return self.__sound


def get_type(self):
    print("Animal")


def toString(self):
    return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kg and say {}".format(self.__name, self.__height, self.__weight, self.__sound)


# create an object call cat of type Animal
cat = Animal('Whiskers', 33, 10, 'Meow')
print(cat.toString())
```

when I run the program it gives me an error that object takes no parameters. but I have described the parameters in the constructor of the class. Please Help.

Comment: Did you indent your code the way you posted it here?  If so, then that is your problem.

Comment: ... because if so, then `__init__()` is not a method, but a simple function and `Animal` only inherits `__init__()` from object, hence the error message.

Comment: Try to start smaller. There's no reason to have more than the constructor for your error. Besides that, Python is not Java. Overriding `toString` in Java is the same as implementing `__str__` in Python

Comment: can you please explain it in a bit details. I am new to python and trying to learn from mistakes..what do u mean by indent the code?? and what can I do to improve it?

Comment: Whitespace is very important. Read through the tutorial. https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax

Answer (score 5):

Make sure all your functions for Animal are indented properly. They need to be inside of class Animal

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by the others, the `__init__` method needs to be indented inside of class Animal for it to be considered a constructor.

But, be careful after you do this. The way that `__name`, `__height`, `__weight`, and `__sound` are declared right now, they are static class variables. However, in `__init__` (by prefixing `self.` in front of the variables) you would be re-declaring instance variables with the name variable names.